# File Upload Control Resting

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using file upload control in asp.net c#..
the actual problem is whenever i select large file using file upload control..just selecting can do anything.. 
Now when i try to reset the file upload control using the clear attributes of file upload control..Now the problem is happens File Upload Control Uploads entire file and then reset the attributes it will take long .. times..
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFUtF.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQAtt.png)

Comment: could you be more clear on your question

Comment: i just want to clean file upload control on button click.. but the problem is if there is large file selected on control.. i will upload entire file and then clean...